# JMeter adding extra quotes to SOAP/XML data from CSV file

Tags: xml, csv, soap, jmeter

I am setting up JMeter testing of a SOAP/XML service. When I did a manual test, it worked fine, when I used the exact same data from a csv file, JMeter is adding an extra quote for every one it finds in the Soap/XML-RPC Data which is supplied as a variable from the CSV file.

Here's the raw data - extracted from the CSV file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-  ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.xxxxyyyy.zzzz.com/ProductDetails"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ProductDetailsRequestDocument><ContextInfo><StoreId>10151</StoreId><CatalogId>10551</CatalogId><LangId>-1</LangId></ContextInfo><SKU>707138</SKU></ns1:ProductDetailsRequestDocument></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

When I paste that into the Soap/XML-RPC Data window, it sends it as-is..however, when I setup CVS Data Set Config to pull the values from a CSV file (delimited by | ), it doubles every " found - as in this example from the View Results Tree Request:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ns1=""http://www.xxxxyyyyzzzz.com/ProductDetails""><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ProductDetailsRequestDocument><ContextInfo><StoreId>10151</StoreId><CatalogId>10551</CatalogId><LangId>-1</LangId></ContextInfo><SKU>529346</SKU></ns1:ProductDetailsRequestDocument></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

Which of course, causes the request to fail with this sort of error as part of the response:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML version &quot;&quot;1.0&quot; is not supported
```

If I change "Allow Quoted Data" in the CVS Data Set config window to "true" it fails with notthing but Error on every request, as the first variable is simply passed as the name and not the CSV value.

I can change my parsing script to strip out the quoates ofmr the SOAP/XML portion, but unsure if that will work, and wonder why I should have to do this, or if there is a more elegant way to approach this. 
Thanks!

Comment: A quick test with no quotes in the SOAP/XML data field in the CSV reveals this corrects the issue. I still wonder why JMeter is inserting the quotes when acquiring the data from CVS and not when input directly.

Comment: show the actual contents of csv before parsing. if you strip out all the quotes, how does jmeter know where to insert them in the xml request? Allow quoted data is for when quotes surround the fields in csv. Your data has quotes embedded, that is different. Are you suggesting that with single quotes, jmeter adds another, but when there are no quotes in the xml, jmeter magically inserts them in the right places? so <?xml version="1.0"> becomes <?xml version=""1.0""> but <?xml version=1.0> becomes <?xml version="1.0"> ??

Comment: I was mistaken. It does not add the required quotes if they are not present.

Comment: I was mistaken as to the source of the issue, I was certain it was JMeter, but the csv files I had problems with had been opened in excel for a look-see and sorting, excel adds the extra quotes when saving the file, as I was able to determine by opening one of the files with NotePad++. I'm sorting from the shell where I am doing the parsing of the source json files, and have no issues. My apologies for this red herring. Or, in the words of the wonderful, never to be forgotten Emily Litella -"Nervemind".

Comment: glad you got it sorted, shame you accepted the answer that masked your problem rather than solving it, before you got a proper answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove double quotation marks from request using the following approach:

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of your SOAP/XML-RPC request
2. Put the following code into PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   String data = sampler.getXmlData();
   data = data.replaceAll("\"\"","\"");
   sampler.setXmlData(data);
   ```
3. Save and execute your test. You can view request details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to verify that XML being sent doesn't contain trailing quotation marks. Don't forget to disable/remove the listener for real load test.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on scripting, built-in types which can be used and sample scripts cookbook.

Comment: this answer does not consider the cause of the issue and simply masks it. better to understand the problem and fix it